# Update a field while changing stage in Kanban Lightning View

Tags: lightning, configuration, kanban

If a validation rule blocks movement or dragging of records or between stages; can those fields be visible/pop up and/or updated easily without having to open the record details?

Comment: Is this 'kanban' an app that you've downloaded from the AppExchange?

Comment: Its the kanban opportunity Lightning view :)

Comment: I don't think this is possible, maybe later they would have something similar to inline edit

Answer (score 0):

It pops up if you locate the validation rule near a field and not at the top of the page.